# Why is the nanoseconds value of time::Duration floored to the nearest multiple of 100 on Windows?

Tags: windows, time, rust

When running the following program on Windows 10 64-bit:

```
use std::time::{Duration, UNIX_EPOCH};

fn main() {
    let d = Duration::new(4660, 22136);
    let t = UNIX_EPOCH + d;
    let d2 = t.duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap();
    println!("d: {:?}", d);
    println!("d2: {:?}", d2);
}
```

Why is the nanoseconds value floored to the nearest multiple of 100?

```
d: Duration { secs: 4660, nanos: 22136 }
d2: Duration { secs: 4660, nanos: 22100 }
```

Windows file times are represented as 100-nanosecond intervals, but I don't understand why that would affect this calculation.

Comment: I don't know Rust, but perusing the source it appears that `UNIX_EPOCH` is a SystemTime, which for Windows is implemented in `libstd/sys/windows/time.rs`. Its implementation of `add_duration` calls `dur2intervals`, which explicitly [divides the nanoseconds by 100](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b1363a73ede57ae595f3a1be2bb75d308ba4f7f6/src/libstd/sys/windows/time.rs#L177) A workaround might be to convert UNIX_EPOCH to an Instant before doing the addition, but I'm out of my depth.

Comment: @Jordan if that's the response of someone who "doesn't know Rust", then you need to start doing some Rust! Being able to peruse source for an unfamiliar programming language and get the right answer is a hard-fought skill.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks! In truth I've read a lot of the Rust book (because I'm that kind of nerd), and it's been at the top of my to-learn list for awhile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding [`UNIX_EPOCH`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/constant.UNIX_EPOCH.html) (a [`SystemTime`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html)) to your [`Duration`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html), you end up with a `SystemTime`.

The [Windows-specific implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.14.0/src/libstd/sys/windows/time.rs) of [`sys::time::SystemTime`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.14.0/src/libstd/sys/windows/time.rs#L28-L31) is based on the Windows `FILETIME` struct.

This structure [has 100 nanosecond granularity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Contains a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

Presumably the choice of `FILETIME` is because that's a pervasive type for time in the Windows world and it offers a good mix of performance and capability.